# Porque la consola se queda en running?

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo el siguiente problema, como tarea necesito simular un videojuego de peleadores y monstruos, hice la clase batalla que es donde se supone que pelean, pero en la clase Main al crear la instancia de batalla, no termina de ejecutar todo el código, he revisado minuciosamente cada línea y no veo ningun error. 
En resumen, para que se entienda (pondré solo la clase Batalla y Main, las demas clases no creo que sea necesario ponerlas y evitar que lean mucho) tengo 2 arraylist donde estan los peleadores que van a batallar (que vienen de la clase Luchador, que no la voy a poner por lo que mencioné) y 1 arraylist de un monstruo. El problema sospecho que esta en el método pelea(), porque llega la consola hasta el resultado del lanzamiento de los dados, pero no me arroja nada despues, debería arrojarme que si gané la batalla o perdí, pero nada, les dejo mi código y un pantallazo de la consola

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Batalla {
    private ArrayList<Luchador> peleadores = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Monstruo> monstruos = new ArrayList<>();
    int dif;

    public Batalla() {
        asignarMonstruo();
        asignarPeleadores();
        lanzarDado();
        pelea();
    }

    public void asignarPeleadores() {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Eliga la cantidad de luchadores que van a la batalla ");
        int cant = leer.nextInt();

        InventarioLuchador.mostrarInventario();
        System.out.println("Elija los "+cant+" luchadores (debe ingresar la posición)");

        for(int i=0; i < cant; i++){
            int pos = leer.nextInt();
            peleadores.add(InventarioLuchador.inventario.get(pos-1));

            System.out.println("Luchador listo para la batalla");
        }
        System.out.println("Luchadores listos");
    }

    public void asignarMonstruo() {
        Monstruo rival = new Monstruo();
        monstruos.add(rival);
    }

    public void lanzarDado() {
        Dado dado1 = new Dado(8);
        Dado dado2 = new Dado(6);
        this.dif = dado1.getCara()-dado2.getCara();
        System.out.println("La diferencia en el lanzamiento de dados es: "+this.dif);
    }

    public int getDado(){
        return Math.abs(this.dif);
    }

    public void ordenVelocidad(){
        ArrayList <Luchador> aux = new ArrayList<>(1);
        for(int i=0; i < peleadores.size();i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j < peleadores.size();j++){
                if(peleadores.get(i).getVel() < peleadores.get(j).getVel()){
                    aux.add(0,peleadores.get(i));
                    peleadores.add(i,peleadores.get(j));
                    peleadores.add(j,aux.get(0));
                }
            }
        }
    } //Este método ordena el Array de peleadores que van a pelear segun sus velocidades, de mayor a menor

    public int casoDado(int daño){
        if(this.dif > 0){
            daño = daño*this.dif;
        }
        if(this.dif < 0){
            daño = daño*getDado();
        }
        return daño;
    }

    public void ataqueJugador(int i){
        double ataq = peleadores.get(i).getAtk();
        if((peleadores.get(i).getFaccion().equals("Agua")&& monstruos.get(0).getFaccion().equals("Fuego"))|| (peleadores.get(i).getFaccion().equals("Fuego")) && monstruos.get(0).getFaccion().equals("Planta")){
            ataq = ataq*1.5;
        }
        if(peleadores.get(i).getFaccion().equals("Planta")&& monstruos.get(0).getFaccion().equals("Agua")){
            ataq = ataq*1.5;
        }
        if(this.dif > 0){
            double daño = (ataq-monstruos.get(0).getDef())*getDado();
            monstruos.get(0).disminuirVida(daño);
        }
        if(this.dif == 0 || this.dif < 0){
            double daño = ataq-monstruos.get(0).getDef();
            monstruos.get(0).disminuirVida(daño); //El metodo disminuir vida esta en la clase Monstruo
        }
    }

    public void ataqueMonstruo(int i){
        double ataq = monstruos.get(0).getAtk();
        if((monstruos.get(0).getFaccion().equals("Agua")&& peleadores.get(i).getFaccion().equals("Fuego"))|| (monstruos.get(0).getFaccion().equals("Fuego")) && peleadores.get(i).getFaccion().equals("Planta")){
            ataq = ataq*1.5;
        }
        if(monstruos.get(0).getFaccion().equals("Planta")&& peleadores.get(i).getFaccion().equals("Agua")){
            ataq = ataq*1.5;
        }
        if(this.dif < 0){
            double daño = (ataq-peleadores.get(i).getDefensa())*getDado();
            peleadores.get(i).disminuirVida(daño);
        }
        if(this.dif == 0 || this.dif > 0){
            double daño = ataq-peleadores.get(i).getDefensa();
            peleadores.get(i).disminuirVida(daño); //El metodo disminuir vida esta en la clase Luchador
        }
    }

    public void pelea(){
        for(int i=0; i < peleadores.size(); i++){
            do{
                ataqueJugador(i);

                ataqueMonstruo(i);

            }while(peleadores.get(i).getVida()<= 0 || monstruos.get(0).getHp()<=0);
            if(monstruos.get(0).getHp()<=0){
                System.out.println("HAS GANADO");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Murio tu luchador");
            }

        }
        System.out.println("PERDISTE LA BATALLA :/");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InventarioLuchador ej = new InventarioLuchador();
        ej.agregarLuchador();
        ej.agregarLuchador();
        ej.agregarLuchador();
        ej.agregarLuchador();
        ej.agregarLuchador();
        Batalla bat = new Batalla();
    }
}
```

La consola me regresa solo esto y se queda pegado en running
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor inicial de la vida de los luchadores y del HP de los monstruos?

Comment: Están hechas con un math random, en la clase luchador y monstruo respectivamente